# How can I correctly create filters for fullcalender plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have a working calendar view in one of my ASP.NET MVC application, I am bringing in my data from the my database in json format through the controller into the fullcalendar jquery plugin to create the calendar with this html and javascript code. How do I create a filter using the select **#Term** dropdowns?

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Calendar";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="heading" style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-bottom: 15px;">
    <h2 style="float: left">Calendar</h2>
    <select id="Term" style="float: right; margin-top: 20px;">
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="2021-2022">2021-2022</option>
        <option value="2022-2023">2022-2023</option>
        <option value="2023-2024">2023-2024</option>
    </select>
 
</div>

<div id="calender"></div>



<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><span id="eventTitle"></span></h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p id="pDetails"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" />

@section Scripts{
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

    <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var events = [];
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/home/GetEvents", 
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                            events.push({
                                title: v.EventType,
                                description: v.School,
                                start: moment(v.Date),
                                end: v.End != null ? moment(v.Date) : null,
                                color: v.Color,
                                year: v.TermYear,
                                school: v.School
                            });
                        })

                        GenerateCalender(events);

                    },

                    error: function (error) {
                        alert('failed');
                    }
                })


                function GenerateCalender(events) {
                    $('#calender').fullCalendar('render');
                    $('#calender').fullCalendar({
                        contentHeight: 400,
                        defaultDate: new Date(),
                        timeFormat: 'h(:mm)a',
                        header: {
                            left: 'prev,next today',
                            center: 'title',
                            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay,agenda'
                        },
                        eventLimit: true,
                        eventColor: '#378006',
                        events: events,
                        eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                            $('#myModal #eventTitle').text(calEvent.title);
                            var $description = $('<div/>');
                            $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Start:</b>' + calEvent.start.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm a")));
                            if (calEvent.end != null) {
                                $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>End:</b>' + calEvent.end.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm a")));
                            }
                            $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>School:</b>' + calEvent.description));
                            $('#myModal #pDetails').empty().html($description);

                            $('#myModal').modal();
                        }
                    })



                }

            })
        </script>
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using such an obsolete version of fullcalendar? V5 is the latest and has better performance and more features

Comment: I decided to use this version because I couldn't correctly figure out how to split my json event source into $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                            events.push({
                                title: v.EventType,
                                description: v.School,
                                start: moment(v.Date),
                                end: v.End != null ? moment(v.Date) : null,
                                color: v.Color,
                                year: v.TermYear,
                                school: v.School like this in version 5.

Comment: Sorry but I've no idea what exactly you mean by "split my json source" or why you think that might be necessary, or how that would be relevant to the version of fullCalendar you're using. All the versions essentially accept event feeds in the same way.

Comment: Thank you ADyson, I mean I spent a lot of time trying to pull my event source which is an array of events I got from the database through my controller into V5 event based on the documentation but I kept getting errors  so I went with this version and it worked. Is it possible for you to show me how to filter this version or its replication on V5 if you have the time.

Comment: It's not clear what specific problem you faced, and the general process is documented by fullCalendar. But I will add a simple guide below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your request in the comments, I will demonstrate how the event feed should be implemented using fullCalendar 5.

Firstly, it does not make much sense to download the events and *then* initialise the calendar. That delays the showing of the calendar, and also means that fullCalendar has no way of requesting new events when needed. You should not simply have your server download all possible events in its database at the beginning - once your calendar has existed for a while and you have lots of events, it can slow the process down to fetch lots of historical events which will probably never be viewed. Instead, your server should provide only the events which fall within the time period fullCalendar is currently displaying. If you implement the calendar setup as I show below, fullCalendar can provide these dates to your server for its use. Then, if the user changes the view to display a different time period, only then will the calendar make another request to your server to fetch the needed events. This is usually more efficient because events are only downloaded if they're actually needed.

Since it appears your server doesn't provide JSON data in exactly the format fullCalendar requires, you need to use the [events as a function](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function) approach shown in the documentation, where you define a custom callback which fullCalendar can execute whenever it needs to fetch events. That callback can then run your AJAX request, get the events from the server and pass them back to fullCalendar (via the provided callback, as shown in the example in the documentation).

Something like this should work for you:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    headerToolbar: {
      left: "prev,next today",
      center: "title",
      right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth"
    },
    events: function(fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) //function to run whenever the calendar needs events
    {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/home/GetEvents", 
        data: { start: fetchInfo.startStr, end: fetchInfo.endStr }, //pass the date range to the server, so it can return only what's needed, not the whole database
        success: function (data) {
          var events = [];
    
          $.each(data, function (i, v) {
            events.push({
              title: v.EventType,
              description: v.School,
              start: moment(v.Date).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
              end: v.End != null ? moment(v.Date).format("YYYY-MM-DD") : null,
              color: v.Color,
              year: v.TermYear,
              school: v.School
            });
          });
    
          successCallback(events); //pass the events back to fullCalendar
        },
        error: function (error) {
          alert('fetching events failed');
          console.log(error);
          failureCallback(error);
        }
      });
    }
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

Relevant documentation:

- https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-globals
- https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function
- https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing

Comment: Thank you ADyson, this is very helpful. I have tried your approach and it worked fine.  Also you are right,  its best the server provides only the events which fall within the time period fullCalendar is displaying. I will continue on adding the pop up and other filters I need.